# Differentiating a volume integral with time

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I encountered the following expression while studying continuity equation derivation in physics.

There is a step where we go from differentiation of a volume integral with time to taking partial derivative with time inside the volume integral.

> $$-\frac{\mathrm{d}Q_{in}}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} { \int_{\nu} {\rho_{\nu}} \mathrm{d}\nu  } {\ } {\overset{?}{=}} -\int_{\nu} {\frac{\partial {\rho_{\nu}}}{\partial t}} \mathrm{d}\nu$$

How does this work? Is this due to Leibniz Rule or Feynman's Trick in multivariable calculus?

Comment: This should be the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Higher_dimensions), yes. The boundary term seems to vanish for some reason in your case, but we would need more information to conclude that.

Comment: @Sobi We are finding volume integral in fixed volume $v$ and $Q_{in}$ is charge in that volume

Comment: Actually we are not taught the mathematics, only physics part is taught

Comment: Since $v$ is fixed, the velocity of the boundary $\mathbf{\vec v}_b$ is zero, and hence the boundary term vanishes.

Comment: @Sobi Thank you! I donot understand it now, but I think I need to read about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Higher_dimensions), yes.

Since $v$ is fixed with respect to time, the velocity of the boundary $\mathbf{\vec v}_b$ is zero, and hence the boundary term vanishes, see also [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem#A_special_case).